# How to copy all rows from one SQL Server table to a table on a different SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

I have a database in SQL Server 2008 and the same database (backup) in SQL Server 2016. All the schema and tables are exactly the same.

I need to copy all rows from a table in SQL Server 2008 to the same table in SQL Server 2016. How to achieve this?

Comment: you need to set link server.

Comment: or you can generate script for that table object (with data) and execute the same script on target server.

Answer (score 1):

1. Linked Server
2. BCP
3. Create new DB, copy the data to that new DB, back it up, restore on target server as a new DB, update the data from Target new DB to existing target DB.

Comment: BCP? "Best Current Practice"?

Comment: bulk copy program utility - native MS SQL Server tool to export/import the data

Answer (score 0):

create your table on the target server using your scripts from the Script Table As / Create Script step
on the target server, you can then issue a T-SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTableNameHere
   SELECT *
   FROM [SourceServer].[SourceDatabase].dbo.YourTableNameHere
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a 1-time extract only, I'd not bother setting up a linked server, but instead I would use the Export Data functionality in SQL Server Management Studio.

To do this, right-click the Source Database in SSMS, then select "*Tasks*" -> "*Export Data*". You can use the wizard to specify exactly what you want to export (I.e. one or more tables, or even data using a query), specify the target, and select whether you want to run the package or save it for later use.

Comment: True in a way, although I have found that more often than not that I need to come back to the original database for more information to be copied/transferred onto the new one. A linked server connection is a very handy way to do that. Although, obviously, you need to realize that  the linked servers can be far away from each other, so you should usually avoid any kind of `JOIN`s on tables between them.

Comment: @cars10 I'm more worried about security implications of linked servers, as well as possible locking issues when querying remote servers. However, as long as one is aware of the drawbacks, it ought to be fine. With that said, in case of a single-use extract, I still think a linked server is like using a cannon to shoot a mosquito.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the use case. My linked servers are all inside a common firewall and are used for inner-company business, so security *is* important, but not as critical as it is for publicly accessible servers. And having the capability of quickly exchanging data between them is a big help to me.

Answer (score 0):

Another Option you can use OpenRowSet like:

```
SELECT * into insertTable FROM 
OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=ServerIP\ServerExtentionNameIfhas;Database=dbname;Uid=uname;PWD=password;'
,'SET FMTONLY OFF;SET NOCOUNT ON;SELECT * FROM fromTable')
```

this will create `automatically` a table name which is inserTable and copy all rows into it.